# What would be the best way to import certain financial ratios of a publicly traded company for a list of companies I have in excel?

Tags: excel, api, import, finance

I have created an excel sheet where I have certain financial ratios in the column section that are important to me for a company and I get a score for how that company is at the end. For example I have a list of stocks that I would like to download the following ratios from a website. (In actual it's way more)

```
PE  EPS     EPS (LAST quarter)  EPS growth YOY  Debt/equity Ratio
```

META
ABNB
NIO

I need help with

1. Downloading the ratios that I want
2. Automate the process for all the Stock Tickers I have on my list as the list can have 30+ which means that I would need to then do repeat the download process 30+ times.

P.S I am a total beginner so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question seems to have a sector-specific component (where from / how to get the specific data) and an I.T. component (how to import into Excel / automate the process). Since Stack Overflow is about the second part, you'd probably have better luck getting responses if you added details about the first part; e.g., which website are you using and what would you be doing for one of these examples if you were doing it manually?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you checked out web scraping? Lots of q&a on here about that.